# How to highlight strings that match pattern in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large set of data that needs to have some visual formatting cues added for visual review.  Essentially the particular matches are phone numbers that have to be matched and when found the row needs to be highlighted.  So far `Conditional Formatting` has not done the trick.  How does one perform such a function in Excel where rows with matching values will be highlighted?

Comment: I once did exactly this with just a handful of lines of VBA. I don't have the code handy right now - it's on a disk I cannot access while I'm traveling - but I remember it was very straightforward. You find the cell, then apply formatting to the corresponding row. You could even fire it off every time the sheet changes, so it's always up to date. Are you looking for "something that looks like a phone number", or specific phone numbers (strings)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is create a conditional formatting rule using a formula, referencing the cell needing to be matched using a partial absolute reference.

For example, with the following Excel sheet:

[image: Excel rows]

1. Select cells A2:C4.
2. Go to conditional formatting->Highlight Cell Rules-> More Rules. (in the Home ribbon tab)
3. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Enter in the "Format values where this formula is true" the equation: `=$B2=$F$1`. Note how the $B2 reference is only absolute for the column, the row is allowed to change.
5. Click the Format button, and choose the format for the cells, and click OK

Now if you change the F2 cell to 1234, you will see this:

[image]

Note that these instructions were for Excel 2013, it may work differently in other versions.

Finally, this question may belong better in https://superuser.com/ , as it isn't really a programming question.

Comment: Thanks, what threw me off here from everything I could find was that I am on OS X Excel and could not find the appropriate "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" selection. This was hidden under the Classic style: http://cl.ly/image/1w3z2X0Y1O3w

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned phone numbers, I believe that you should use a lookup function in the conditional formatting:

[image]

Then enter a lookup formula. I use `MATCH` to do the lookup and `ISNUMBER` to confirm whether there is a match or not:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$5,0))
```

[image]

And there you go!

[image]